# How to get NavMesh polygons in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Question is simple, but i can't find answer on the land of internet. How to get all polys of navmesh, how to find closest ones, how to find centers of these polys, how to find polys connected to specific one, and so on?

Does unity even allow this kind of staff or you need again to download something from github or buy some on asset store?

I find this post https://forum.unity.com/threads/accessing-navmesh-vertices.130883/
but it help find only vertices, not polygons or something..

So, does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution**:

```
    var navMesh = NavMesh.CalculateTriangulation();
    Vector3[] vertices = navMesh.vertices;
    int[] polygons = navMesh.indices;
```

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshTriangulation-indices.html

> Triangle indices for the navmesh triangulation.
>   Contains 3 integers for each triangle. These integers refer to the vertices array.

Should be the points in each polygon if I'm not mistaken.

---

**Other useful methods**:

https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.SamplePosition.html

From this source: "Finds the closest point on NavMesh within specified range."

https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.Raycast.html

"Trace a line between two points on the NavMesh.
bool True if the ray is terminated before reaching target position. Otherwise returns false. "

https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.FindClosestEdge.html

"Locate the closest NavMesh edge from a point on the NavMesh."

---

What exactly are you needing the navmesh data for?

Comment: Basically I wanted to implement some path finding algorithms. I know unity propose A* algorithm, but I wanted to implement them by myself for training and learning NavMesh by itself.

Comment: In that case. you probably wanna calculate based on the sample position and if the closest edge is a given distance away (meaning there is space enough). Your character can then attempt at getting closer to the point.

Another solution is to calculate your own navmesh or make your own coordinates. For example by making small squares that the player moves between. You can make the squares invisible to the player if they shouldnt be seen.